# Overlay 3D Surface Plot over 3D Globe in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to place a 3d surface plot over a globe in MATLAB. I can't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
% Sampele Data
longitude = [1 2 3]
latitude = [3 2 1]
elevation = [12 21 13; 15 14 15; 12 16 15]

% Create Globe
figure
axesm('globe')
gridm('GLineStyle','-','Gcolor',[.8 .7 .6],'Galtitude', .02)
load coast
plot3m(lat,long,'k')
view(3)
axis off; zoom(2)

% Overlay Surface Plot
mesh(longitude,latitude,elevation)
surfm(longitude,latitude,elevation)
```

Comment: "What" doesn't work?  What is the error message?

Comment: I really been at this for awhile.  No error message but the figure is distorted.  If you load the code in the command window, you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not obvious, your code actually seems to work fine.

To see it, first remove the line `mesh(longitude,latitude,elevation)` because it does not plot in longitude-latitude coordinates.

The problem now is that the `surfm(longitude,latitude,elevation)` only draws a tiny area which is hard to spot. Too locate it, comment out the line `plot3m(lat,long,'k')`, run the script and notice your tiny surface in the right half of the globe.

To demonstrate that your script is working, you could also replace the last line by

```
surfm(lat(1:200),long(1:200), rand(200,200))
```

to randomly color a part of the south pole.

By the way, shouldn't your last line read `surfm(latitude,longitude,elevation)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the few guidelines.